# Formula for Case Subject in Process Builder

Tags: formula, process-builder, case

Am looking for assistance in how to construct a formula within process builder to show two IDs in a case subject
Current code is;

```
[Case].Migrated_Case_Number__c  & 
IF(NOT(ISBLANK([Case].WRM_ID__c))," | " & "WRM ID: "&[Case].WRM_ID__c,
IF(NOT(ISBLANK([Case].ICMS_ID__c))," | " & "ICMS S/O: "&[Case].ICMS_ID__c, 
IF(NOT(ISBLANK([Case].iTools_ID__c))," | " & "iTools WP: "&[Case].iTools_ID__c,
IF(NOT(ISBLANK([Case].OUT_ID__c))," | " & "OUT/Fault: "&[Case].OUT_ID__c,
IF(NOT(ISBLANK([Case].NCR_ID__c))," | " & "Audit Result Number: "&[Case].NCR_ID__c,
IF(NOT(ISBLANK([Case].Track_Trace_Number__c))," | " & "NCR ID: "&[Case].Track_Trace_Number__c,""
))))))
&
IF(NOT(ISBLANK([Case].Affected_Address__c))," | " &[Case].Affected_Address__c.Name,"")
```

What I am trying to achieve is having the case subject show both WRM ID and ICMS S/O if both are populated. Currently, it will only show WRM ID if it is populated and ignore the ICMS S/O.
[![Picture of current case and subject][1]][1]

I assume I have to put in similar logic to the affected address on the last line but I am not quite sure about the best way to do it in code so that WRM ID still shows FIRST in the case subject with ICMS S/O showing second and address last.

Something like,

```
[Case].Migrated_Case_Number__c  & 
IF(NOT(ISBLANK([Case].ICMS_ID__c))," | " & "ICMS S/O: "&[Case].ICMS_ID__c, 
IF(NOT(ISBLANK([Case].iTools_ID__c))," | " & "iTools WP: "&[Case].iTools_ID__c,
IF(NOT(ISBLANK([Case].OUT_ID__c))," | " & "OUT/Fault: "&[Case].OUT_ID__c,
IF(NOT(ISBLANK([Case].NCR_ID__c))," | " & "Audit Result Number: "&[Case].NCR_ID__c,
IF(NOT(ISBLANK([Case].Track_Trace_Number__c))," | " & "NCR ID: "&[Case].Track_Trace_Number__c,""
)))))
&
IF(NOT(ISBLANK([Case].WRM_ID__c))," | " & "WRM ID: "&[Case].WRM_ID__c,
&
IF(NOT(ISBLANK([Case].Affected_Address__c))," | " &[Case].Affected_Address__c.Name,"")
```

Please help!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CP4lN.png

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten the code to work so that WRM now appears as well as ICMS

```
    [Case].CaseNumber   & 
    IF(NOT(ISBLANK([Case].iTools_ID__c))," | " & "iTools WP: "&[Case].iTools_ID__c,
    IF(NOT(ISBLANK([Case].OUT_ID__c))," | " & "OUT/Fault: "&[Case].OUT_ID__c,
    IF(NOT(ISBLANK([Case].NCR_ID__c))," | " & "Audit Result Number: "&[Case].NCR_ID__c,
    IF(NOT(ISBLANK([Case].Track_Trace_Number__c))," | " & "NCR ID: "&[Case].Track_Trace_Number__c,""
    ))))
    &
    IF(NOT(ISBLANK([Case].WRM_ID__c))," | " & "WRM ID: "&[Case].WRM_ID__c, "")
    &
    IF(NOT(ISBLANK([Case].ICMS_ID__c))," | " & "ICMS S/O: "&[Case].ICMS_ID__c,"")
    &
    IF(NOT(ISBLANK([Case].Affected_Address__c))," | " &[Case].Affected_Address__c.Name,"")
```